# How can I make serve command to use environment.ts instead of environment.prod.ts?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 8 with Angular CLI. My app settings is stores in environment.ts and environment.prod.ts. *serve* and *build* commands are using environment.prod.ts.

**I need *serve* command to use environment.ts instead of environment.prod.ts.**

**UPDATE:**

This is my serve command:

```
ng serve
```

And this is my *Angular.json* file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "UI": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/fontawesome/css/all.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/fonts.iransans.css",
              "src/assets/css/fonts.titr.css",
              "src/assets/css/fonts.yekan.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/custom.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UI:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "UI:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UI:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "UI-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "UI:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "UI:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "UI"
}
```

Comment: `serve` should use `environment.ts` by default unless you pass in the `—prod` flag.  Are you using that flag?

Comment: @Pace I added the serve command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "Auto Import" ability of the VS Code. It added the wrong path automatically. This is the imported line:

```
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment.prod';
```

And it should be like this:

```
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
```

If someone has this problem, first check the import paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit you angular.cli.js accordingly.

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts"
  }
```

And you can use this flag to pass your environment when doing the serve.

```
--environment={envName}
```

You can get a good idea by going through this [article](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/).

Answer (score 0):

Which one are you using

ng build/serve

or

npm build/serve

If you’re using ‘npm’,
Pls make your scripts are correct in package.json

Comment: I'm using *ng serve*

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your serve with something like `npm start`, then that is driven by "scripts" in your package.json.  If this is how you are starting your project, check there to see what the "start" script is running because it might be set with a `--prod` flag (e.g. `"start": "ng serve --prod",`) or is referencing a different configuration; it should default to environment.ts unless it is running with the `--prod` flag or a different configuration (e.g. `--configuration=production`).

Otherwise, for angular 8, your settings are in your angular.json file and you should check under "projects" > "" > "architect" > "build" > "configurations" > "local" to see if you have any fileReplacement settings like this:

```
"fileReplacements": [{
  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
 }],
```

If you do, either delete the contents of "local" so it is just empty braces `{}` or change the "with" value to be `"with": "src/environments/environment.ts"` instead and then your ng serve should go back to pulling from environment.ts.  Or you can make an entirely new configuration altogether and reference it in your build with a `--configuration=<configuration name>` flag (if you do this though, don't forget to add a "browserTarget" under "serve" > "configurations"> "" like `"<project name>:build:local"`).

Comment: Thanks. But there is not any local configuration there. I added the Angular.json to the question.

Comment: You could add local and ensure that your local build uses the file replacement you choose.

Comment: Then what should I write into local part? There should not be any file replacement. Should it remain empty? an empty local part? I added my Angular.json file to the question. Have a look please.

Comment: You could add within the `"local": {}` braces the fileReplacements section above and put "with": "src/environments/environment.ts" and then you're sure that it is replacing your environment.ts with your environment.ts when you build locally.  To be clear, you shouldn't *need* to do this, but this is a way for you to try to weed out the issue.  For example, you could make an environment.blah.ts with different variable values and point to it and see if it changes.